# Why does my GitHub pull request show so many code additions?

Tags: github, request, branch, pull

My typical workflow is to create a new branch, and occasionally merge in changes from master. Let's say I add a total of 100 lines of code to my branch. Let's say there are +1,000 lines of code changed on master. When I go to create a new pull request, I end up seeing +1,100 lines of code. It seems that GitHub is incorrectly diffing master from my branch.

When I do the pull request, I select the base branch as master, and the comparison branch as my branch. Shouldn't GitHub make the comparison such that the pull request only shows +100 lines of code?

In other words, why is GitHub showing master's LoC additions/subtractions with my branch's additions/subtractions? In the past, I've created "clean branches" when I'm done to fix this. That involves diffing the branch from master, creating a patchfile, creating a new branch from master (which becomes the "clean" one), and then applying that patch to the clean branch. Once I've done that, the diff cleanly shows only my code additions/subtractions. This happens on both iOS and Rails repos, where I'm using XCode and Sublime 3 respectively.

Comment: Could you link specific commit/PR?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since these are private repos.

Comment: I see. Could you reproduce issue with minimal code in public repo?